# iOS 9.3.5, App crashes upon opening

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

Before I begin, I’d like to point out that this device is around a decade old, so it’s basically operating on vestigial barbarian servers at this point. Anyway, this device, whenever I try to open a certain app (Plants vs. Zombies 2) decides to crash after loading to about the EA logo. For context, no other apps do this.

These are the solutions I’ve tried without any results

1. Power on and off (done about seven times)
2. Clear up storage
3. Check for updates

PS: Buying a new iPad is currently not an option, so I‘m looking for ways to make this work with the hardware I have.

Comment: Have you tried deleting then downloading the game again? The App store still lists it as compatible with iOS 9 and later. You may lose your saved games and whatnot, but perhaps you may be able to play again.